# Sql sort on first character of column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this query that sorts on a 2-character column. I would like to sort only on the first character of it. Is this possible using order by____.

Comment: What would be the difference between sorting by the first character of a string and the entire string?

Comment: Yes of course! Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `SUBSTR` function can return the first character of a string.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY SUBSTR( SomeField, 1, 1 )
```

`SUBSTR` takes three parameters, the field to sort, the 1-based start position, and the number of characters to return.

Per my comment above, I maintain that there is no meaningful difference in the output of this and

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY SomeField
```

Comment: I just want one character, because it is initials and I only want to sort by the first one, then sort by last name